# error installing rosjava using rosws

Tags: ros, rosws, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I tried to follow the instruction here (http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html)
to install rosjava using rosws and got an error during the last step : rosws update

Error shows:

ERROR: Error processing 'rosjava_core' : checkout() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'

Any idea of this problem? Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32712/error-installing-rosjava-using-rosws/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-26**:
What version of ROS? What host operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This probably means the rosinstall version is newer than the vcstools version or vice versa.

On Ubuntu, do

```
sudo pip install -U rosinstall
```

or

```
sudo easy_install rosinstall vcstools
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0